# Need to hide input fields depending on the users choice

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have currently a school project and there is a final piece that needs to be done.

I currently have a form where the user can write in detailed information about a "weapon idea" to a game. However the user need to make a choice, the user have 3 different choices and depending on what they pick some input fields needs to become invisible. I am using php and jQuery/javascript to get it to work.

Example php text:

```
<form action="create-a-weapon.php" method="post">
<input type='hidden' name='reloadtype' />
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
            Base damage:
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type='text' name='Base_Damage' id="Base_Damage" value='<?php echo $Base_Damage; ?>'>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            Max Damage(Maximum rampup):
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type='text' name='Damage' id="Damage" value='<?php echo $Damage; ?>'>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            Pellets:
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type='text' name='Pellets' id="Pell" value='<?php echo $Pell; ?>'>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

As you might notice I have used one of the input fields as 'hidden' because my friend told me that the hidden fields need to be stored there. He have unfortunately gone away so I can't get any help from him. I have tried to search for it online but I can't find any that looks like it. I am not that good at javascript/jQuery and I hope anyone can help me.
I have added sources and all because I use some fields to calculate the input(so I can write out DPS and such).

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script/calculate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

reloadtype

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Choose your reload type">
<!--<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px  0;"></span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>-->
<select>
  <option value="shells">Shells and projectiles</option>
  <option value="clip">Clip</option>
  <option value="No reload">No reload</option>
</select>
</div>
```

This is the dialog window in javascript

```
$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
resizable: false,
height:240,
width: 340,
modal: true,
closeOnEscape: false,
open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog).hide(); },
buttons: {
"Ok": function() {
$( this ).dialog( "close" );
},
}
});
```

Thank you before hand
-AM

Comment: Can you go into detail about `reloadtype`?

Comment: Updated the stuff because the javascript part didnt show.

Comment: Edited with reloadtype

Comment: Why not just use `<select name="reloadtype">`?

Comment: I am not sure what to think of that.

Because if the user choose option 'Laser' the input field 'Pellets' need to be "placed" in the hidden field.

Comment: Where does the user select `Laser`?

Comment: It was a stupid example, sry about that. If the user choose one of the three choices in the dialog: Shells, Clip or No reload. If he choose 'Clip', there are no 'pellets' etc
The pop up appear when the user visit the page.

Comment: So selecting clip should hide the pellets text field?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="script/calculate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.reloadtype').change(
                    function() {
                        if ($(this).val()=="clip") {
                            $('.pellets').hide(500);
                        } else {
                            $('.pellets').show(500);
                        }
                    }
                );
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="create-a-weapon.php" method="post">
        <input type='hidden' name='reloadtype' />
        <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    Base damage:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type='text' name='Base_Damage' id="Base_Damage" value='<?php echo $Base_Damage; ?>'>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    Max Damage(Maximum rampup):
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type='text' name='Damage' id="Damage" value='<?php echo $Damage; ?>'>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="pellets">
                    <td>
                    Pellets:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type='text' name='Pellets' id="Pell" value='<?php echo $Pell; ?>'>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Choose your reload type">
        <!--<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px  0;"></span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>-->
        <select class="reloadtype">
          <option value="shells">Shells and projectiles</option>
          <option value="clip">Clip</option>
          <option value="No reload">No reload</option>
        </select>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have this code that works with button click:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#hideshow').live('click', function(event) {        
jQuery('#content2').toggle('hide');
});
});
</script>
```

then on the field :

```
<?php
<p><input type="button" value="Load Template" id="hideshow" />
<div id="content2" style="block">
```

or you can use @php to check on the selected value.